# Reviewing/voting tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Recently I proposed two tag synonyms. These two proposals are currently still pending and with 0 votes.

Is anyone ever looking at these proposals?

Is the SE system actually notifying users with sufficient privileges clear enough? Or is it lacking here?

Comment: Aparently the wish to have notifications was already specified since Nov '13: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204244/improving-tag-synonyms

Answer (score 2):

It seems only moderators can see/accept them, and it should be listed in their tools
https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

We have only 3 Moderators currently: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Answer (score 2):

You have to have at least 10 votes or something on a tag to suggest and vote. I have at least for bundle-product <-> bundle suggestion not enough rep on the tags :(

Is there a link I can check the recommendations?

> Is anyone ever looking at these proposals?

No, only suggestion on my own.

> Is the SE system actually notifying users with sufficient privileges clear enough? Or is it lacking here?

No clue, I don't think so :)